# idevAffiliate unexpected output after signup

Tags: php

In the lastest idevaffiliate there is no longer a generic mailing list integration. The previous version made an API call (im not a developer) to my mailing list manager (Interspire Email Marketer - IEM) and when someone signed up at idev they were added to a mailing list at IEM.

There is however a API trigger for new accounts. The difference as far as I can see is that the main IF differs in the trigger to the generic mailing list file.

It used to start:

```
if ($MailingListAuth == true) {
```

But now starts:

```
if ($NewAccountAPITrigger == true) {
```

Then the call is made.

Problem is that now I get some output on the page after a new account is created. The output is:

```
Response: 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (1) { [0]=> string(4) "2936" }
```

And the the page as normal (it appears top left of page).

BUT the new account user IS added to the mailing list so the call works, but not sure why or how to eliminate the output at the top left of the page.

Here is a condensed version of the account trigger file with the main parts intact and as mentioned working except for the output in the top left of the screen?

```
<?PHP
if ($NewAccountAPITrigger == true) {

$username = check_type('username');
$email = check_type('email');

$xml = '<xmlrequest>
<username>MyAdminLoginNameGoesHere</username>
<usertoken>MyTokenGoesHere</usertoken>
<requesttype>subscribers</requesttype>
<requestmethod>AddSubscriberToList</requestmethod>

<details>
<emailaddress>'.$email.'</emailaddress>
<mailinglist>1</mailinglist>
<format>html</format>
<confirmed>yes</confirmed>

<customfields>
<item>
<fieldid>2</fieldid>
<value>'.$username.'</value>
</item>

</customfields>
</details>
</xmlrequest>';

$ch = curl_init('https://maydomainname.com/xml.php'); //CHANGE TO THE PATH OF YOUR IEM INSTALLATION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false) {die("Error performing request");}
//var_dump($result); //for debugging purposes
//Example of how to display returned data
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS' && empty($xml_doc->data)) {die('Status is 
success. Empty response.');}
if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS') {
        echo 'Response: <br />';
        var_dump($xml_doc->data);
} else {
        echo 'Error is '. $xml_doc->errormessage;
}
}
?>
```

As mentioned the user IS added to the mailing list so this basically works but would appreciate any help I can get to resolve this. Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are seeing is from these two lines:

```
echo 'Response: <br />';
var_dump($xml_doc->data);
```

- [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) means "display this text on the page".
- [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) is a function for "dumping" (outputting) a value to the screen, usually for debugging purposes.

It's up to you what you want to display / do instead, but you would probably get value from either an introductory programming course, or a friendly developer who will do minor fixes for you in exchange for beer tokens.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP much appreciated. Strange then that it never appeared with the previous version using the MailingListAuth == true variable. If I get further issues I have the question here at stackoverflow and so can get you that bear. lol Thanks again.